# designing a mains powered car jump starter

Tags: voltage-divider, mains, automotive, high-current, lead-acid

Would it be possible to jumpstart a car using mains power?

I'm talking about a device that plugs into a 240V AC mains power outlet, and clamps onto a 12V DC lead acid battery.

Here are the main specs on a typical (and my) lead acid battery:

Cold Cranking Amps: 550
Reserve Capacity Minutes: 95
Amp Hours: 55

So, to the average consumer, it would basically be like plugging an extension cable into the wall socket and the other end just clamps onto the battery terminals.

Is it possible to do something like this with a stepdown transformer or some kind of bridge circuit or voltage reducer circuit or similar?

even if it's not an ideal solution, i'd still be interested to experiment and explore this avenue.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It depends on what kind of components uoy allow to be used to build this. If you calculate power you need to start a car and power available from mains socket you will see it is not possible directly. Do you allow for charging of supercaps for few minutes before trying to start the car for few seconds?

Comment: Odd question, of course it's possible. I'm not sure what the actual question is here.

Comment: @pipe the question is whether or not it's possible to achieve and if so, how.

Comment: @Justme sure, if you can see a way forward like that, i'd love to know more. i will consider any and all suggestions.

Comment: Such products already exist. For almost the price of a car battery, you can get a portable device with a car battery inside it, complete with mains charger and jump start cables. That's how they are done.

Comment: @Justme sure but that is basically just charging a battery and using it to jumpstart another. two things i'd like to avoid: charging time, relying on a second battery. i guess the goal is ultimately improved convenience.

Comment: If you keep it charged you can always use it immediately. Works even if mains electricity is down, or in the middle of a forest. Directly starting a car from single phase mains without any energy storage device is not practical, even if in some instances is possible (you have paid for electric service of large enough rating, fuses, wires, etc).

Comment: Car chargers with start function are not at all unheard of.  A 120V/15A circuit provides enough power.  The ones that include a lead acid or lithium ion battery are fancier newer products.  Slightly older and cheaper models have slow charge, fast charge and engine start modes, and older ones yet are just battery chargers.

Answer (score 3):

200A * 12V = 2400W

So it would be in the realm of possibility from a 240V 16A socket. However a starter can require much more surge current than that, so if all you have is a 240V 16A socket, and a 12V 3600W DC supply, that would make a rather wimpy car starter.

This is never done in practice because it makes no sense to buy an expensive, high power DC power supply and use it for five seconds every year, at most... and it won't deliver enough power anyway.

Also it would be more expensive than a battery.

It makes a lot more sense to use a battery charger to charge the car battery, then use that to start the car.

Pretty much the only practical solution cost-wise is to put a [super high current LiPo battery](https://www.amazon.fr/NOCO-GB40-Ultrasafe-D%C3%A9marreur-Chargeur/dp/B015TKUPIC) in the device along with charge & management electronics, although that does introduce other spectacular failure modes... But it also makes it portable, which is useful if the car you want to start is not in your garage.

Comment: so how is it that a small 12V DC lead acid battery can provide such a high current and mains cannot.

Comment: Lead acid batteries are very good at providing high current due to very low internal resistance. It's just a useful property of this battery chemistry, of course the drawback is they're very heavy and low capacity per weight, but also cheap. Note you can get a [12V 200A](https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-power-supplies/all-application/all-power-format/12/200/ac-dc-single-output-enclosed-power-supply-output-rsp--3000--12?returnurl=%2fen-gb%2fac-dc-power-supplies%2fall-application%2fall-power-format%2f12%2f200%2f%23rsp-3000-12) supply, but it will cost $400.

Comment: interesting. how is it achieved? is it much cheaper to build your own?

Comment: That is because a car battery is specifically meant to start cars, so it can provide a lot of instantaneous peak power for a short time. Household single phase mains can't do that, you are limited by having certain wiring which has been protected by circuit breakers with certain ratings minus other loads on the same circuit.

Comment: @voices This one is a high power switching power supply, very difficult to DIY due to custom high frequency transformers (need an expert for that) and other stuff like high voltage + high current making all sorts of failure modes a lot more "spectacular", requires expensive probes to debug without zapping your oscilloscope. Also very lethal, of course.

Comment: You could use a good old "big iron" transformer, but it will be the same weight and size as a welding rig, about 30 kilos for 3 kW. So it's much more cost effective to use a cheapo charger for half an hour, in the end...

Comment: Also, a 12V 400A supply would not be able to provide 400A when connected to standard household mains plug. It would require a 25A circuit.

Comment: @bobflux can we explore that further? even if it's not ideal, it might still be useful. now you mention it, i have an inverter welder that reaches ~200A and is quite small

Comment: Pretty much the only practical solution cost-wise is to put a [super high current LiPo](https://www.amazon.fr/NOCO-GB40-Ultrasafe-D%C3%A9marreur-Chargeur/dp/B015TKUPIC) battery in the device, but that does introduce other spectacular failure modes... But it also makes it portable, which is useful if the car you want to start is not in your garage!

Comment: The mains **can** provide a high current, and that's why it's fused, so that it doesn't for more than a few milliseconds.

Comment: This product does actually exist in Canada, contains no battery and is relatively cheap ($40).  For larger batteries or systems with a lot of cranking needed, you can pre-charge the battery a bit, but for mid size cars and trucks the start mode is sufficient even from a dead battery.  The transformer hums like mad, so I'm sure they're overdriving it, but it's only on for 30 seconds to a minute while you start the car, so mine has been used quite a few times and shows no sign of wear.  Also worth noting it runs off a 120V/15A circuit, so the vehicle you could start with 220V would be huge.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly it is possible. To get 550 A from a 240 V source requires about 30 amps. That would be a circuit comparable to an electric clothes dryer circuit. It requires a transformer, rectifier and a filter capacitor. There would probably need to be a provision for preventing the capacitor from drawing too much charging current when the device is turned on.

You could make the input current draw as low as you want with energy storage, but you could just as easily use a spare battery and simple charger.

Comment: 30A 240V AC is what i'm workin with